# Testing dynamic expando with XUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamic, caliburn.micro, xunit.net

So I'm trying to test a method from an injected dialog API is being called (Using CaliburnMicro MVVM framework).

**Method**

```
public bool? ShowDialog(Screen dialog)
{
    dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
    settings.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    settings.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    return _dialogAPI.ShowDialog(dialog, null, settings);
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to test it:

**Test**

```
[Fact]
public void DialogServiceCallAPIToShowDialog()
{
    var dialogAPI = new Mock<IWindowManager>();
    dialogAPI.Setup(x => x.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<Screen>(), null, It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>())).Returns(() => true);

    var instance = new DialogService(dialogAPI.Object);
    instance.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<Screen>());

    dialogAPI.Verify(x => x.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<Screen>(), null, It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>()), Times.Once, "Fail...");
}
```

**Problem**

XUnit fails telling me this:

> Message: Moq.MockException : "Fail..." Expected invocation on the mock
>   once, but was 0 times: `x => x.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<Screen>(), null,
>   It.IsAny<Dictionary<String, Object>>())`
>
> Configured setups:  `x => x.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<Screen>(), null,
>   It.IsAny<Dictionary<String, Object>>())`
>
> Performed invocations:  IWindowManager.ShowDialog(null, null,
>   [[WindowStartupLocation, CenterOwner], [ResizeMode, NoResize]])

I suppose it has something to do with the data type I'm passing to the `Is.Any`method, but I'm not sure. Any idea?

Comment: This `instance.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<Screen>());` is the problem. You are not actually passing a value into the methods under test. It is meant to be used solely in the Moq expressions.

Comment: If you were check the result of the `ShowDialog` it would be `null` as well.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I replace that with a concrete screen just for test purpose. Problem is with the Setup of the `ShowDialog` vs its execution.

Comment: Yeap, but I'm not checking for result (that's another Unit Test) I'm just checking a call is being made to the WindowManager.

Comment: My point about the result being null is that if the mock was configured correctly and executed as expected the result would be true.

Comment: Thanks @Nikosi, you were right. By reading your comments I could determine that I was passing to Moq the wrong Screen type. There are two objects with the same class name :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to replace:

```
It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>()
```

with

```
It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>()
```

in `Verify` call. Because `ExpandoObject` you passing in `ShowDialog` implements `IDictionary` but is not `Dictionary`.

Here is a code I tested with:

```
public class Screen {

}

public interface IWindowManager {
    bool? ShowDialog(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);
}

public class DialogService {
    private IWindowManager _dialogAPI;
    public DialogService(IWindowManager dialogAPI) {
        _dialogAPI = dialogAPI;
    }
    public virtual bool? ShowDialog(Screen dialog)
    {
        dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
        settings.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        settings.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        return _dialogAPI.ShowDialog(dialog, null, settings);
    }
}
```

Your code fails, while replacing `Dictionary` with `IDictionary` passes fine:

```
var dialogAPI = new Mock<IWindowManager>();
dialogAPI.Setup(x => x.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<Screen>(), null, It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>())).Returns(() => true);

var instance = new DialogService(dialogAPI.Object);
instance.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<Screen>());

dialogAPI.Verify(x => x.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<Screen>(), null, It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>()), Times.Once, "Fail...");
```

Comment: I had already tried like this; but it does not work. I've solved temporally by using a Dictionary argument instead of It.IsAny, but that is not the optional solution.

Comment: Strange, I verified before posting. Can you post exact signature of IWindowManager.ShowDialog?

Comment: `bool? ShowDialog(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);`

Comment: @ErreEfe still cannot reproduce (I mean with your code it fails but replacing with `IDictionary` fixes it). Included code I tested with in answer.

Comment: Evk. Solved, thanks. Was a harder one to fix. Why? There are two `Screen` clases. One the external Screen which is used by Caliburn and its dialog API. The other one used in the software I'm testing. Moq was telling me that the expected result was a call to a method expecting the same `Screen` parameter as for initialization of service, but there are two different.